# Python construct for naming string constants

Tags: python

Often I use string constants such as:

```
DICT_KEY1 = 'DICT_KEY1'
DICT_KEY2 = 'DICT_KEY2'
...
```

Many of those times I don't mind what the actual literals are, as long as they're unique and understandable to the human reader.
This way it is easier to refactor and change a literal across the project.

So my question is, is there a standard way to make these string constants declarations simpler? I don't want to repeat writing the literal `'DICT_KEYn'`.

For example, something like this could work:

```
@string_consts
class DictKeys:
    DICT_KEY1: str
    DICT_KEY2: str
    ...

assert DictKeys.DICT_KEY1 == 'DICT_KEY1'
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for enums? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/enum.html#module-enum

Comment: With enums, he'd still have to specify the string value explicitly.  The decorator from @AKX seems like the way to go to get this for "free", which is I think what the OP was looking for.

Comment: Yes exactly, enums can give me numbering for free, but not string literals, for which I will still need to write them explicitly. (afaik)

Comment: You could use [enums with automatic values](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it helps, the implementation for your `string_consts` decorator would be

```
def string_consts(cls):
    for key, value in cls.__annotations__.items():
        if value is str:
            setattr(cls, key, key)
    return cls
```

This makes

```
@string_consts
class DictKeys:
    DICT_KEY1: str
    DICT_KEY2: str

assert DictKeys.DICT_KEY1 == 'DICT_KEY1'
```

as in your example work OOTB.

Comment: Great, is there a standard implementation for this? Or at least a pip package that implements something similar?

Comment: Since the implementation is 5 lines, there's no real need for a package, is there? You have my blessing to vendor those 5 lines into your project. :)

Comment: Already did:) But then I might want to add a parameter such as `lower=True` that would make the strings lowercase and the plot thickens...
You could say the same about other constructs like dataclasses, `@suppress` and many other sweeteners, and yet - they found their way into standard Python.

Comment: But on the other hand, the standard library is where libraries go to die, they say...

Answer (score 1):

When at global level, you could do something like this:

```
for i in range(100):
  globals()['DICT_KEY'+str(i)] = 'DICT_KEY'+str(i)
```

At class level, `setattr` could be used in the same way:

```
for i in range(100):
  setattr(self, 'DICT_KEY'+str(i), 'DICT_KEY'+str(i))
```

If your keys are not a numeric list as suggested by your question, you could still do this:

```
for key in ['KEY', 'OTHERKEY', 'SOMEOTHERKEY']:
  globals()[key] = key
```

In my opinion, this is way easier to understand than using the decorator solution - and does the job.

Comment: These solutions screw with any sort of static analysis or code completion though (and smell too magical to me).